# My LAN cable connection doesn't work, when I have usb drive plugged

Tags: connection, hard-drive, cable

I bought new raspberry pi 4 with 8 GB ram, and it behaves strange- while it has connected external usb drive, which has it's separate power supply and I power up rpi, it doesn't connect to the local network, even tho, light from RJ45 port lights up. When I an testing it with ping from another computer it says "host unreachable", but when I wiggle this cable a little, then suddenly ping responds and connection is stable while rpi is powered on.

Such behavior doesn't appear when none of the disks is connected to the usb port. It just boots up and ping responds after a minute. I want to emphasize, that external HDD has its own power supply, so I guess it is not caused by the power drop.

I tested it several times, and I wonder if I was unlucky and my rpi is broken, or maybe it is something that happens for this version. I wanted to ask you guys, because I'm not sure if I should give it back to the shop and buy the same version or any another one.

Comment: 'when I wiggle this cable a little' - not sure what cable but that's an obvious place to start with a replacement I would have thought???

Comment: wiggle LAN cable, but as I mentioned, it works without any problems when usb drive is not plugged, so I assume, that this is no cable problem.

Comment: What operating system do you use? Do you find something related in the journal? (`journalctl -b -e`)?